# Newest Mplab software that works with Ubuntu and ICD2

Tags: software-installation, kubuntu, hardware, compatibility, g++

I have an **old ICD2**, used with an **old version of MPLAB Integrated Development Environment (IDE)** under **Windows**.

Now I need to use this hardware again for a microcontroller but my OS is nowadays **Kubuntu LTE**.

The **old version of MPLAB** that I used under Windows **does not have a Linux version**.

Sadly the **newest version of MPLAB** (MPLAB® X IDE v3.20) that I installed on my Kubuntu successfully **does not support ICD2 anymore**.

So, my question is, what's the newest version (does exist?) of MPLAB that **still supports ICD2 and is Linux compatible?**

[Here](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/devtools/dev-tools-parts.html) is possible to find old downloadable MPLAB versions but I cannot find the release notes about ICD2 compatibility.

Thank you very much in advance to who can help me to solve me this problem and avoid me to buy ICD3 or worst install Windows again.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem some years ago. It is not possible to use an old ICD2 in GNU/Linux with the old [MPLAB IDE](http://www.microchip.com/development-tools/downloads-archive) or [MPLAB X](http://www.microchip.com/mplab/mplab-x-ide), but you may use [Piklab](http://piklab.sourceforge.net/) to use the ICD2. The issue here is that Piklab is not as a good IDE as the old MPLAB. I have used the old MPLAB under [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) in Ubuntu 12.04 very succesfully, programming the ICD2 from Piklab. It is not as smooth as you may wish, but it works. The other option is to use the ICD3 with MPLAB X; this is fully supported to work under GNU/Linux.